# How does add indent in WebStorm when use Ctrl + Alt + L

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How does add indent in WebStorm when use Ctrl + Alt + L (formatting code)?

I want to see that result.

[image]

or

[image]

I want that it was in all .ts file e.g..

Comment: would you need indent being added to the empty line? Can't be done on code formatting

Comment: @lena I want that it was in all .js file e.g..